# Testcafe hangs and keep sending requests to browser heartbeat for desktop browsers but works fine for headless mode

Tags: testing, browser, automated-tests, testcafe, heartbeat

On starting test execution, page frame gets loaded but no JS, images. When checked in the network tab of Dev tool testcafe keeps sending heartbeat to a browser which returning **200 status**.

```
Request URL: http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/browser/heartbeat/v0missQ
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: xxx.xx.xx.xxx:12555
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

{"code":"ok","url":""}
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of your Web application and a test, so that we can reproduce the problematic behavior on our side?

Comment: I've run into this when executing a lot of tests and concurrency of 3. Helped me to break apart the test run into multiple commands.